# Rails cloud application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openshift

I have deployed this application to OpenShift:

**http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo**

Randomly, when visiting the site I get some really slow responses and I can't find out why.
I checked my db's status and seems to be ok (caching etc).

I wonder if there is some kind of setting I have to check/set on the Rack server. It doesn't happen to my local server (unicorn). Feels like the server is "sleeping" if not in use for a while.
It's a Rails4 app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty obviously this has something to do with your cloud service.  You need to ask them.  Heroku's virtual servers, for example, go to sleep (swapping your job out to disk I expect) unless you are paying for at least two of their server units (called dynos).  Waking up takes about 20 seconds.  Maybe your service has something similar.

Comment: @Gene I didn't know that, I'll check to see if something similar happens on OpenShift too. Thank you

Comment: setup some cron or alive check like pingdom to keep the instance of your app up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Openshift will Idle inactive gears. If an application hasn't had an external request in 48 hours the the gear is spun down. It will automatically spin back up once a http request is sent to the application.

Comment: Ok but this is not the case, it happens several times during the same day.